# A contradiction quite possibly due to my poor understanding of time dilation

Tags: special-relativity

Let a rod move past a mark which is stationary in the reference frame $S$ with a relativistic speed, Let it take a time $t$ to do so, In the frame of a rod this will take time $t'$ and clearly due to length contraction in $S$'s frame $t'>t$.

But if the rod experience's a time $t'$ then due to time dilation the time passed for an observer in the frame S will be $\gamma t'$ so here $t>t'$ which contradicts our original inequality .

What went wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion is occurring because both observers sees that the other's one clock run slower. That is why you get the opposite  result in the inequality.